# Mysql connection URL openshift

Tags: mysql, openshift

How do I see MySql connection URL from openshift? I need it to use it in hibernate.cfg.xml
When I log onto my account online I only see the username and password.

Answer (score 2):

On open shift the database is already available in JNDI. It's name is jdbc/MySQLDS.

To use this 'datasource' in hibernate, your hibernate.cfg.xml should look something like this:

```
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/MySQLDB</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Mapped annotated entity-->
    <mapping class="org.hibernate.tutorial.domain.Event"/>

</session-factory>
```

To help you even mote please tell us if you are using JbossEWS 1.0, 2.0, JBoss AS6, JBoss EAP. Is your app scale, etcetera.

Comment: I am using JBoss app server 7

Comment: I am new to hibernate too. so for   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://${env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/${env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}
   </property>

Comment: No, in stead af using <property name="hibernate.connection.url"> use <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource"> as described above. JBoss already has a datasource set up for your application(s)